# Why I use parameter typescript, but still generate javascript project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, infragistics

I follow https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-react/react/components/general-getting-started

```
npx create-react-app MyAppName --typescript

npm install --save igniteui-react
npm install --save igniteui-react-charts igniteui-react-core
npm install --save igniteui-react-excel igniteui-react-core
npm install --save igniteui-react-gauges igniteui-react-core
npm install --save igniteui-react-grids igniteui-react-core
npm install --save igniteui-react-maps igniteui-react-core
npm install --save igniteui-react-spreadsheet igniteui-react-core
```

but result

[image]

Why I use parameter typescript, but still generate javascript project?

Comment: `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript` your are missing the template flag.

Comment: Thanh you! The reference document is wrong.

Comment: create react app is no longer maintained use vite instead...